# asking or to ask?

Tags: grammar

Could you please tell me which one is correct?(and why?)

I sent an email to the company asking them for more information.

I sent an email to the company to ask them for more information.

Answer (score 0):

Both are correct, with a slight nuance in the meaning:

"I sent an e-mail asking...": grammatically you're saying that your e-mail (or yourself) was asking for more information. *Asking* is a present participle which functions rather like an **adjective** qualifying your e-mail (or yourself).

"I sent an e-mail to ask...": grammatically you're describing the purpose of your e-mail; you sent it in order to ask / so as to ask for more information. *To ask* is a **verb** expressing the purpose of your e-mail.

Comment: Your nuances are correct, but there's virtually no practical difference in the overall meanings.

Comment: Agreed, @Barmar. In this case the meaning is  practically the same. Yet the use of the infinitive expresses more INTENT than the use of the gerund/present participle. You would say "I love swimming", expressing a general feeling, but "I'd love TO swim in this river" expressing the desire possibly to have a swim there and then. Wouldn't you?